# The caller was not authenticated by the service when calling from Ruby?

Tags: .net, ruby, wcf, web-services, soap

I need to consume a SOAP web service using the Savon Ruby client. I think the endpoint is written using the .NET framework, and, in fact, we currently have a .NET client library provided by the service team.

When using the client library, it works perfectly and data is retrieved sucessfully, but when using the Savon client, I'm getting:

```
(a:InvalidSecurity) The caller was not authenticated by the service. (Savon::SOAPFault)
```

The thing is, we already checked the SOAP requests, and both seem to be the same. The only difference is that one is done using Ruby and the other is done using .NET.

Below are a couple examples of both requests:
.NET client

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<Identity xmlns="http://vauto.com/webservices/Haystak/1.0/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <AccessId>2A6B3F9FC49D1F4388AF7064045D964E</AccessId>
  <AccessStamp>2014-01-31T16:46:07.1597194-05:00</AccessStamp>
  <Signature>et0KyY1ZnjCM5z7BhQR9Q3Fj7V4=</Signature>
</Identity>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
<GetVehicles xmlns="http://vauto.com/webservices/Haystak/1.0/">
  <request xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <EntityId>TEST01</EntityId>
  </request>
</GetVehicles>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Ruby client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:wsdl="http://vauto.com/webservices/Haystak/1.0/" 
            xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Header>
    <Identity xmlns="http://vauto.com/webservices/Haystak/1.0/"
              xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <AccessId>2A6B3F9FC49D1F4388AF7064045D964E</AccessId>
      <AccessStamp>2014-02-03T10:24:50.3690365-05:00</AccessStamp>
      <Signature>ykKc5tWCyY9UVb+zw50hfAxOnSA=</Signature>
    </Identity>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
  <wsdl:GetVehicles>        
    <request xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <EntityId>TEST01</EntityId>
  <EntityName i:nil="true" />
  <HaystakId i:nil="true" />
  <Vins i:nil="true"
          xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
    </request>
  </wsdl:GetVehicles>
</env:Body>
```

The WSDL for the web service is as follows:

[image]

Any help is greately appreciated. I'm kind of lost and don't know what else to try in order to consume that web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

- Your two SOAP requests are structurally very different, one is a `<wsdl:GetVehicles>` request (Savon) and the other is a `<HelloWorld>` (.NET).
- The order of the tags in your header is different.  Ideally, this should not make a difference, but if the XML API on the server is retarded it can make things misbehave.
- Your .NET identity block is namespaced but your Savon identity block is not.
- Your Savon request has a namespace `xmlns:wsdl="http://tempuri.org/"` which looks invalid.

SOAP is a misnomer, because it's not simple, and I've always thought that it is monumentally more difficult when you make calls between Microsoft and non-Microsoft ecosystems.

First steps first, ensure you are generating the same request in both clients, and take it from there.  Identical requests should elicit identical responses.

Comment: +1. "SOAP is a misnomer, because it's not simple"... hmmm, I thought they were being sarcastic when they said it was simple. "...if the XML API on the server is retarded it can make things misbehave." - so incredibly true. "Identical requests should elicit identical responses.", yes, definitely so. That's what we expect when we build any sort of service.

Comment: @theTinMan you haven't lived till you've seen a SOAP server implemented in regex... and you're the poor bastard who has to interface with it.

Comment: I'd do my best to break it so they have to write it correctly.

Comment: Is there a way to change savon's <wsdl:GetVehicles> per just GetVehicles? I configured everything to match by hard coding the message except per that wsdl

Comment: In the end as suggested on the responses the problem had to do with using wsdl:GetVehicles instead of plain GetVehicles